# CSS stop div moving upwards

Tags: css, material-ui

I have a search box, when I start typing I get a dropdown list of suggestions. However, the searchbox div element moves upwards as well as downwards. How do I stop the div from moving upwards?
Code snippet here displays a hardcoded unordered list of names for simplicity and conciseness.

```
<AppBar style={{ height: 60 }}  position="fixed" >
        <Toolbar color="inherit" >
            <div style={{ border: '1px solid grey', boxShadow: '0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 2px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.18)', backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'black'}}> 
            <input style={{  border:'none', boxSizing: 'border-box', padding: '10px 5px', outline: 'none' }} value={text} onChange={this.onTextChanged} type="text" />
            <ul style={{listStyleType: 'none', textAlign: 'left', margin: 0, padding: 0, borderTop: '1px solid grey'}}>
            <li>Jack</li> 
            <li>Joe</li> 
            </ul>
            </div> 
        </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

Comment: please post your code here on stackoverflow and create a miniimal version so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please a include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've updated the question. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this css in your `<ul>` tag

```
.ul{
position:absolute;
background:white;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks